# 2 iframes in 1 page

Tags: html, iframe

So yeah I already did some research about it here, didn't find a good solution.
I tried to put 2 iframes in 1. JSfiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/g1v99z62/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>

        <title>XD | ICT | Monitoring</title>

        <style>
            body {
                background-color: #343535;
                font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
                color: #ffffff;
                font-size: 14px;
            }
            h2 {
                font-weight: bold;
            }
            #servid {
                background-color: #F5F5F7;
                padding: 5px;
                color: #343535;
                display: inline-block;
                margin-bottom: 1px;
            }
            iframe {
                margin-top: 0px;
                width: 100%;
                height: 500px;
            }
            #iframecpu {
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
                width:100%;
                height:100%;
            }
            #iframeram {
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
                width:100%;
                height:100%;
            }
        </style>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="servid">
                WELCOME
        </div>


        <br />

        <div id="iframecpu">
            <iframe src="http://www.google.com"></iframe>
        </div>

        <br />

        <div id="iframeram">
            <iframe src="http://www.yahoo.com"></iframe>
        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

I checked everything twice.. But it is not showing content..
Why is that?

What am I still doing wrong? (Besides using iframes at the first place. But this is just a single page so I can monitor multiple graphs which are published on different urls. So please don't shoot me for using iframes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one work :

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>

        <title>XD | ICT | Monitoring</title>

        <style>
            body {
                background-color: #343535;
                font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
                color: #ffffff;
                font-size: 14px;
            }
            h2 {
                font-weight: bold;
            }
            #servid {
                background-color: #F5F5F7;
                padding: 5px;
                color: #343535;
                display: inline-block;
                margin-bottom: 1px;
            }
            iframe {
                margin-top: 0px;
                width: 100%;
                height: 500px;
            }
            #iframecpu {
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
                width:100%;
                height:100%;
            }
            #iframeram {
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
                width:100%;
                height:100%;
            }
        </style>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="servid">
                WELCOME
        </div>


        <br />

        <div id="iframecpu">
            <iframe name="iframe1" src="https://jsfiddle.net/">
            <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
            </iframe>
        </div>

        <br />

        <div id="iframeram">
            <iframe name="iframe2" src="https://jsfiddle.net/">
            <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
            </iframe>

        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

Just to be sure it's not the browser the this one works your problem is the website you choose. (google and yahoo)

Comment: I just did.. But it didn't work.. And I'm using latest Firefox, Chrome and Edge..

Comment: I just edit my post and find a solution it works for me tell me if it's ok for you

Comment: I think the problem is the website you choose for execute the iframe. And you have to put a link balise <a> for focus your iframe.

Comment: It's strange when I try it in the snippet mode of StackOverflow it works.

Comment: Ok I got it ! If you work in Jsfiddle you have to put the link of their website in the iframe like src="https:// jsfiddle.net/". If you do this in both iframe you can see a result

Comment: Thank you for the last reply. It is working! But what is "link balise" ? I know that back in the "iframe days" a simple <iframe src="..."></iframe> was more then enough.. Is this because of the new HTML5 standards?

The addition of the <a href> is working.

Comment: I don't know why but when I try another website he don't want to let us see the result it's the same when I try to put only the iframe balise.. And you're welcom I'm happy for you enjoy you project code ! ^^

Comment: See above comment! I marked your answer as a working answer.. Thanks mate!

Comment: Forget it I try the iframe balise alone and it works too you can change your code it's more clean whitout <a> balise :) I edit my post !